# What is the correct format for xpra password files?

Tags: password, authentication, file-format, xpra

I  created a username/password combination of the form `onetwo:bucklemyshoe`, ie the password file contains the single line `onetwo|bucklemyshoe`

Whenever I try to connect the message appears on the logon page:

```
You were disconnected for the following reason:

invalid challenge response
```

The logs display the following message

```
 Authentication required by password file authenticator module
  sending challenge for username 'onetwo' using hmac+sha256 digest
 Warning: hmac+sha256 challenge for 'onetwo' does not match
 Warning: authentication failed
  invalid challenge response
 Disconnecting client Protocol(ws websocket: 111.111.111.111:14333 <- 222.222.222.222:35555):
  invalid challenge response
```

It makes no difference whether `Insecure plain-text passwords` is checked or not.

The contents of the password file is not what xpra expects. Is the actual format documented somewhere? Is there an utility or script to create them in the right format?

Comment: This probably depends on your system and version. The command line man page [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xpra.1.html) says use `username|password|uid|gid|displays|env_opts|session_opts`

Comment: I tried the `tcp-auth=pam` option and that worked and that logged me straight into the desktop, but I don't like exposing desktop login details on the internet. I prefer a separate set of credentials for the web login page, then the user would then apply their desktop login details after the desktop page comes.
I prefer a common page protected by http-auth, then the standard html client page, then the desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [xpra mailing list](http://lists.devloop.org.uk/pipermail/shifter-users/2018-February/002093.html) where this was also asked, the password file format is documented [on the wiki](https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Authentication):

> ## Password File
>
> "file" vs "multifile":
>
> - "file" contains a single password, the whole file is the password
> - "multifile" contains a list of authentication values, see proxy server file authentication - this module is deprecated in favour of "sqlite" which is easier to configure.

To make a regular password file, you just write the password in plaintext:

```
echo -n "bucklemyshoe" > yourpasswordfile.txt
```

Comment: I suppose points are due for providing an answer based on a question I asked on the mailling list :)